# Apptha Marketplace vs Webkul Mangeto Marketplace. Which one is better UI/UX support, cost?

Tags: magento2, marketplace

Have any of you guys used any of these extensions for marketplace website for CE? Or would you just recommend going with Magento Commerce?

I'm trying to setup MVP, proof of concept marketplace website with prob 5~7 vendors  with 50 products each from vendors.

I was wondering how long it will take to build the website and what type of add-on extensions you recommend to purchase (necessary extensions)

Please share your previous experiences!

Comment: i suggest webkul magento marketplace